Select max value within group in GraphQL query
I am trying to create a query in GraphQL on a data set that looks like this:
Data:



Id
version
name
value




1
1
a
banana


1
1
b
boat


1
2
a
courgette


1
2
b
car


2
1
a
eggplant


2
2
a
fennel


2
2
b
ferry


2
3
f
french fries



I want to create a query that only returns the rows where version has the highest value for each id. The desired output on the table above should be:



Id
version
name
value




1
2
a
courgette


1
2
b
car


2
3
f
french fries



Is this possible using GraphQL only or do I need to do this filtering within group after receiving all the data?

GraphQL is an API interface and doesn't have anything to do with the underlying data or the filtering implementation. What have you tried? Are you using a database? What programming language/library are you using?

The data is, as far as I know, in an Oracle database serverside. We use GraphQL as API to access this data. We mainly use R, Python or Power BI to access the data. That could be done with a query like this:
query data{Data{id version name value}}.
In order to speed up the retrieval of data, we would like to make a query that would only retrieve rows that  are related to the highest value of version within each id. But I have troble finding any specifications on how this can be done. It can easily be done in e.g. Python, but that will still require more data to be sent from the server

It has to be done on the server side and exposed by a new query.

GraphQL API is just a way to describe the interface. You will have to program the implementation in any case.
I would implement this task like this:

Define a new query in your GraphQL API. For example - lastVersions.
Implement the logic of the select in SQL. To select the rows with the highest version in Oracle DBMS, you may find it useful: FIRST_VALUE.

